# Windows 8.1 multi monitor "show desktop" work just for current monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

Is it possible to click "show desktop" so that affects only the current monitor (and not all of them which happens by default)?

Comment: I have a problem with your question - if you click on the task bar to show desktop, then you've changed which monitor is the current monitor...

Comment: If i click on show desktop on monitor1 , then all monitors minimize their windows . If i click on show desktop on monitor2 , then all monitors minimize their windows . I want if i click on show desktop on monitor1 , only that monitor minimize windows .

Comment: In Windows 8.1 right bottom corner of screen .